# can controllers be separate files while sharing data between controllers through a service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I'm doing something like this: 
[How to create separate AngularJS controller files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087627/how-to-create-separate-angularjs-controller-files)

But I'm trying to share data between these separate controllers using a service. I'm unable to do it. Can you tell me if its even possible to share data between controllers(that are in separate files) using one service in the app.js file?

Comment: Yes I do this all the time. Maybe you could share some more code? Or a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you're following the advice from the answer to the linked question, you're probably just forgetting to include all the files in your index.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444100/angularjs-how-to-http-get-data-and-store-it-in-service, this is the problem i have, but is no way mentioned to share the http response between controllers. can anyone help?