# Angular Js : '$q.defer is not a function' error

Tags: angularjs, q, angular-promise, angular-services

After Refering this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444100/angularjs-how-to-http-get-data-and-store-it-in-service) , I am trying to get JSON data into my angular service.

**Service:**

```
.factory('restservice', ['$rootScope','$http', '$q', '$log',
function($rootScope,$q, $http) {
return {
    getData: function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('xyz.com/abc.php', { cache: 'true'})
        .success(function(data) {
            defer.resolve(data);
        });

        return defer.promise;
      }
};
}])
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('RestaurantsCtrl', function ($scope,$http, restservice,restViewservice){

      restservice.getData().then(function(data) {
      $scope.Restaurants = data;
    });

})
```

After Implementing this console says **'$q.defer is not a function'**.

What's the issue here? Please Help ...!! Am new to Angular Js so forgive if something is wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$q.defer`, just return your `$http.get(..)`. also, `success` is deprecated - use `then` instead.

Comment: thanks for that ! :)

Comment: Such a nice thing that people ask their questions on Stackoverflow, I'm sure this question and also the answer solved many people's problems. Thanks for this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have wrong service definition:

```
factory('restservice', ['$rootScope','$http', '$q', '$log',
function($rootScope, $q, $http) {
```

Should be:

```
factory('restservice', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', '$log',
function($rootScope, $http, $q, $log) {
```

---

<sub>Common mistake :)</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That was quick ! worked ! i feel stupid for being a noob in angular now.  i thought that won't matter. well thanks

Comment: Everyone makes this type of errors, me also,  after 2 years of angular. No worries :)

Comment: @Maxxim Shoustin   can you help with cache. the above http get object is not getting cached. I am using anular js to build app with ionic. this default caching wont work in mobile apps ?

Comment: @SumeetDarade on mobiles like Cordova all data should be stored in native (a.e. SharePreferences for Android or UserDefaults for iOS or sqlite if you have a lot of data and need some manipulation). Also since angular is MVC, the model should be defined in native also and not in services like in Web.

Comment: @SumeetDarade Further, All http calls I suggest you to make in native and not in Angular (aka JS) because if you expect a lot of users, some devices have bugs with sending http data

Comment: actualy its the matter of one JSON object thats used to populate list. since its just a single object thats of importance i planned on caching it.  Cordova has plugins for storage options like sql. But  , i didnt wanted to do that just for single json object and was finding a easier way out.  about http , ionic uses angular js so i had to

Comment: To clarify this answer further, the inject parameters and function parameters differ. In the answer above, the `$log` was missing from the function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same error and resolved now:

Please refer angular 1.6.1 version file, since older version of angular gives the above error.